# How can DJICameraLaserMeasureInformation of Zenmuse H20/H20T be used in iOS?

Tags: dji-sdk

How can I obtain a [DJICameraLaserMeasureInformation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera_DJICameraLaserMeasureInformation.html) value in my app code?

Comment: i`m not quite sure what you are asking.  The point of having a Laser on the camera is for the user to tap on the center of image and gets to know distance to the target or the GPS of the target for some tasks such as drone delivery or send police.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghaiyeah, I'm just wondering how I could use that distance measurement directly in my own code. I see this data type in the API but haven't found how to access it.

Comment: you can check whether your code included this in Headers/DJICameraSettingsDef.h  if not try download the beta version that has it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: there's a `DJILensDelegate` method (in DJILens.h):

```
 - (void)lens:(DJILens *_Nonnull)lens
         didUpdateLaserMeasureInformation:(DJICameraLaserMeasureInformation *)information;
```